# django dynamic zipper internal server error

Tags: python, django, zip

I have debugging enabled, but it doesnt show anything. All I see is "500 Internal Server Error.
What am I doing wrong in this script?

python

```
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import cStringIO as StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

def zipit (request):
  files = ['/home/dbs/public_html/download/codex/video.html', '/home/dbs/public_html/download/audio/audio.html']
  buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
  z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
  [z.write(f) for f in files]
  z.close()
  response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(z), content_type='application/zip')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=z.zip'
  return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/x-zip-compressed")
```

Comment: it should be `def zipit (request):` don't forget about the `:`

Comment: Sorry, when I copied my code over, the ":" didnt come with. I already had it in my source and its not the problem. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: RuntimeError: Attempt to read ZIP archive that was already closed

Comment: yep cause the file was closed as such when response tries to open it again it can't.

Comment: @samy.vilar How do I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import cStringIO as StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
import os

def zipit (request):
    files = ['/home/dbs/public_html/download/codex/video.html', '/home/dbs/public_html/download/audio/audio.html']
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, "w")
    [z.write(f, os.path.join('codex', os.path.basename(f))) for f in files]
    z.close()
    buffer.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(buffer.read())
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=z.zip'
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip'
    return response
```

but please try not to have django return binary files it was never design for this, your http server should handle it.

Comment: I got something to download from this but when I try to open the downloaded zip it says "The archive is either in a unknown format or damaged"

Comment: ok tested it should work now but keep in mind that it that write will keep the path of the files.

Comment: beautiful, How would I revise this to ONLY include the directory before the file in the path. example `/home/dbs/public_html/download/codex/video.html` would be saved as `codex/video.html`

Comment: Ok updated by default if you don't specify the arcname it will use the filename which includes the path to the file, unless you inteded it to be so.

Comment: simply pre-append the directory you want to the filename to generate the appropriate archive structure.

Answer (score 0):

The above workaround works but has the disadvantage of loading the entire zip into memory and not taking advantage of the filesystem. If you are creating a large archive this could result in a serious memory burden on your application. Here's a similar approach that will allow you to leverage the filesystem:

```
# imports omitted
def zipfileview(request):
    fd, fpath = tempfile.mkstemp()
    os.close(fd) # don't leave dangling file descriptors around...
    with zipfile.ZipFile(fpath, "w") as zip:

        # write files to zip here

        # when done send response from file
        response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(fpath, 'rb')), mimetype="application/zip")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=myzip.zip"
        return response
```